# Does the US really use C64 computers for the launch control of their missiles?

Tags: realism, ncis-los-angeles

In Season 09 E07 of *NCIS: Los Angeles* we can see the inside of a launch control center for nuclear missiles.

The two terrorists that brought the control center under their control are clearly using a Commodore C64 (from the 80s!) for entering the coordinates.

Here are two screenshots from the scene that I am referring to:

[image]

[image]

I can't believe this is true.

Comment: Would be nice if the downvotes explained what is so bad about the question.

Comment: At a guess I'd assume a lack of research. I found the answer in a couple of minutes with a quick google search.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference of the US Army using C64 computers...

Comment: This question is not even about movies or TV, it's about actual **Air Force** (the branch in charge of all nuclear weapons except those deployed by submarines) technology. So that might explain the downvotes. The remaining mystery is why it's not on hold yet.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: so what is the tag "realism" for then?

Comment: Interestingly this will no longer be the case. Although ground to a halt because of.. the past couple of years happened.. they are back on the job of replacing all of that with fancy new digital gear that they now also have to make sure is safe against.. hackers.. Seems the issue is the old tech really is too hard to keep going anymore and they've run out of spares, etc, so in walks the new tech guy... Otherwise, back-to-NCIS-tv-show: sticking an unmodified C64 in there is, I think, very lazy set decorating.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, yes, they are using 1970/80s technology

Here's a section of a visit by *60 minutes* which shows the inside of a silo and covers the reasons for the older tech.

[Article covering the same](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2614323/Americas-feared-nuclear-missile-facilities-controlled-computers-1960s-floppy-disks.html) for those with lower bandwidth.

## Using it means that cyber access is essentially impossible.

There is no internet access, they use the old *giant* floppy discs etc.

also

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for finding the answer... but could you précis it for those of us too idle [or limited bandwidth] to watch the videos?

Comment: No.. **obviously not** but essentially it's the same level of technology. The TV series just used what was to hand to *simulate* the inside of a silo.

Comment: @Paulie_D the C64 is *newer* than the 1970s missile-launching tech... :)

Comment: At least the C64 big lump of putty colored plastic with large gray keys is a good approximation of older keyboards production company to use under an extremely tight budget...

Answer (score 1):

They use exactly what they were built with.... in the 1980's. They "can't" be modernised, nothing is compatible.... Nor is it necessary. The system works. One of the issues the government has with the silos is that the companies that made many of the components have been out of business for years. There aren't even drawings, much less someone to make a one off for a replacement part. No fear, we have "lots and lots" of silos around the country. They don't all need to work.